# Does Gherkin have any negation?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I am used to something like NOT in specifying conditions - but perhaps it will only allow distinct positive conditions? e.g. If the user is not anonomous

Comment: Can't you write a "negative" step and then have a corresponding step definition that validates the negative condition?

Comment: You can write a step that takes (is|is not) and uses that to check that it is true or not depending on the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a not operator in the gherkin syntax.  As @orde has said in the comments, you just have to write a negative step definition that checks for what you want.

One thing that can make this a little nicer to use is knowing that you can write steps using the 'But' keyword instead of only using 'And'

```
Given I have set something up
When I do something
Then something positive should happen
And some other thing should happen
But some negative thing should not happen
```

Not a huge difference but sounds nicer.

As Dave McNulla has said you can write your steps to take 'is | is not' if you want to reuse them.